# Create an Array of Strings of a sheet column stored at Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

This supposed to be a simple thing to do, but i`m having a hard time to find this answer.

X-Code / Objective-C:

I have an sheet stored at Parse.com, and I simply want to make a array with one of its columns. For example, I have a spread sheet called Places and I want to build an Array of the column Address of these places, but instead I`m getting an Array of objects. Look!

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Locais"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"local"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


    self.colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:objects];


    NSLog(@"%@", objects);


}];
```

The log:

```
"<Locais:fEQq2qB8dJ:(null)> {\n    local = \"Giga CCM/CCS\";\n}",
"<Locais:z3gHNJ7CPw:(null)> {\n    local = \"Giga Santander\";\n}",
"<Locais:rNEJUHPXtl:(null)> {\n    local = \"Sean Plott\";\n}"
```

How I want to get the log:

"Giga ccm/css"
"Giga santander"
"Sean Plott"

Comment: Why do you want to modify the log ?

Comment: I don`t want to modify the log. The log was just the way i found to show how the xcode is getting the information. What i want is an array with 3 strings instead of an array with 3 objects. I can`t find a way to extract data from this array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the array of strings in a single step using `Key-Value Coding (KVC)`,

```
self.colorArray = [objects valueForKeyPath:@"local"];
```

You should have a look on [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data from the array like this :

```
PFObject *localis = objects[1];
NSString *string = [localis objectForKey:@"local"];
```

This is how you can get the data out of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for tour reply!!! But the question is: what if i want to build an Array from those strings!? i only can mount with objects! that`s my problem. i know how to extract one single row from the column "local", but i can`t mount an array with they components?